# changing value of hidden input fields depending on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, tcl

I have multiple forms in my page and depending on the hidden input value, different sections are called.

Now my issue is, I have 2 input buttons in one of my forms, and depending on what button I click i need to send the appropriate hidden input type,

For example in the below form .
If i click on Generate password button,
I want the target value(the value of the hidden input field)  as generate_password

If I click on Lock Password I want the target value to be user_locked. Here is my code.

```
    puts "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"target\" value=\"user_locked\">"
    puts "<tr><td colspan='4'> New User request Review</td></tr>"
    puts "<tr><td><label for=\"full_name\"> Full Name </label></td>"
    puts "<td><input type=\"text\" value =\"$name\" name =\"full_name\" readonly=\"readonly\"></td>"

    puts "<tr><td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Generate Password\" onclick=\"if(confirm('Are you user you want to add this user?')){submit()};\"></td>"
    puts "<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Lock User\" onclick=\"if(confirm('Are you user you want to add this user?')){submit()};\"></tr>"
```

well basically I am calling different functions depending upon the hidden field,

```
set target "";      catch { set target $CGI_DATA(target) }
switch $target {
    "confirm"   { set id [UpdateUserData $id] }
    "user_locked    { DeleteUser $id }
    "user_confirmed"        { NewUserConfirmed}
    "newuser"   { NewUserReview }
    default     { }
}
```

Comment: please give the output (html), not the code that generates it...it'll be easier to figure out.

Comment: i added stuff to my question. For this application I would prefer javascript than jquery. The problem that i might encounter is , i am already using lot of EXTJS framework in that page and in my experience mixing jquery with it creates problems. But I wouldnt mind trying out the jquery solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to your onclick event could do that when confirming instead of just submitting the form. If you use jQuery:

```
if(confirm('Are you user you want to add this user?')){
    $("input[name=target]").val('Generate password');
    submit();
}
```

The one for the other input button should be very similar.

It is also possible that you have a way of knowing which button was pressed to submit the form another way. If I remember correctly, in PHP at least the name of the button is passed through in the _REQUEST variable.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="target" name="target" value="user_locked">
```

...

```
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" id="generate_button"/>
<input type="button" value="Lock User" id="lock_user"/>
```

In JS (jQuery):

```
$("#generate_password,#lock_user").click(function(){
    ("#target").val($(this).attr("id"));
    $("form.myform").submit();
});
```

You can change around the IDs and classes of these elements, but make sure the JS and HTML match up.