# Hidden input has value before submit set in Javascript; once submitted it is null on the backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework

I have a Play application which has a hidden input field that has a value set via Javascript before the form is submitted.  The field is set correctly on open and before and after the submit process.  However, when it gets to the controller, it is set to `null`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log("ptp.load value = " + 
$('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val());
});

$("#cancelButtonBottom").click(function () {
$("#ptp").submit();
console.log("ptp.submit AFTER - final value = " + $('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val());
});

$("#ptp").submit(function (event) {
$('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val("No");
console.log("ptp.submit BEFORE - final value = " + $('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="remedy_Institutional_Costs" value="@adultInstitution.getRemedy_Institutional_Costs()" />
<button type="button" id="cancelButtonBottom">Exit</button>
```

When the form loads, the value is "No":
[image]

When I click the `Exit` button, the value is still set to "No":
[image]

However, when it makes it back to the controller, the value is set to null:
[image]

I found a few posts, but they didn't help me out:

[Check Hidden Form Input has Value on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519081/check-hidden-form-input-has-value-on-form-submit)

[changing value of hidden input fields depending on submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666752/changing-value-of-hidden-input-fields-depending-on-submit-button)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you post the full controller code (or at least the part of the code that receives the value from the form)?

Comment: Just do your `$('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val("No");` before your `$("#ptp").submit();`

Comment: @JustinT. You are wrong.. The first submit() submits the form - the redefinition of it doesn't happen - not executed.

Comment: Another thing to point out is that you don't have `form` object in your HTML - meaning you can submit a single `input` field - will need to use AJAX for it.

Answer (score 0):

As @D.V.D. has suggested, you are setting the value of the hidden input *after* the `submit()` event has been triggered. This means that even though the data has not yet been submitted, the event handler has already received data it intends to submit, which at the time of the event, is *null* for your hidden input. To remedy this, you could check the value upon the `submit()` event and set it/resubmit if necessary:

```
$("#ptp").submit(function (event) {
    var inputValue = $('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val();
    if(inputValue.lenth == 0){ //value is null, set it and resubmit
        $('input[name="remedy_Institutional_Costs"]').val("No");
        $("#ptp").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding id="remedy_Institutional_Costs"  to the remedy_Institutional_Costs element. I know when posting data to a controller by serializing the form the element won't be  present if both the ID and name attributes aren't present.